# Error with jsonpCallback. Internal Server Errror

Tags: web-services, jquery-mobile, cordova, jsonp, asmx

I'm trying to access ajax (jquery-mobile and PhoneGap) to a web service (asmx), but something is wrong and what is not.
This is the js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    url         : webMethod,
    data        : param,
    dataType    : 'jsonp',
    jsonp       : 'callback',
    jsonpCallback   : 'jsonpCallback',
    success     : function(data) {  
                   alert(data.nombre);  
                  },
    error       : function(x,y,z) {
                   alert("-- " + x+'\n'+y+'\n'+z + " --");
              }
    });

    function jsonpCallback(){
        alert("OK");
    }
```

and the web service (asmx)

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void WebServiceTest()
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
  string qs = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["jsonpCallback"];
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(qs + "( [{ \"name\": \"John\", \"message\": \"Ok\"}] )");
}
```

When I run the debug gives me an error -->

callback=jsonpCallback&_=1343139529496 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have already tried a thousand things (or at least that's the feeling I have ...)

I would greatly appreciate your suggestions.

P. S. Forgive my poor English

Comment: Did you check the url `webMethod` if It's valid or not?

Comment: Yes, it's valid. it refers to the domain, the asmx page and the name of the service (http://www.domain.com/asmx/WebServiceTest)

Comment: "Internal server error" tells you where the problem is. Have you checked that your web service actually works?

Comment: Yes, i cheked. I put the address of the web browser and log correctly.

Comment: Do I should add a sentence to the web.config file?